# How to pass an Activity as parameter in function

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to create a function that receives an Activity as parameter and with it, it will change to that activity. But if I use the `.class` of an Activity to call the function, it changes the parameter of that function to a `Class<{Name}Activity>`, and so it will only accept that activity.

For example. Calling the function:

```
sendUserToActivity(MainActivity.class);
```

How it is defined:

```
private void sendUserToActivity(Class<MainActivity> activityClass) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, activityClass);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And if I try another call:

```
sendUserToActivity(LoginActivity.class);
```

It gets an error. Since the parameter of the function is established as the Class MainActivity, of course it won't accept another Activity, so how it should be defined to accept another Activity?

Comment: Can you try using just Class<Activity> instead of Class<MainActivity>?

Comment: It doesn't work. It asks to import the Activity class and after that it only display error on both "MainActivity.class" and "LoginActivity.class" when calling the function

Comment: Why do you need to pass activity? You need only object of activity?

Comment: Passing the entire activity was my first thought

Comment: looks like you need to use the activity context maybe?

Comment: use Class <? extends Activity>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
private void sendUserToActivity(Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, activityClass);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This way you're using generics and everyone that extends activity will be accepted, so your code is adaptable to every activity that you want.

Comment: That works! I would never think this could be written, thanks!

Comment: No problem, read a bit about generics if you can, it's really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, how to do it in your case:

```
private void sendUserToActivity(MainActivity activityClass) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activityClass, activityClass.getClass());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: But, would it receive others Activitys even declaring MainActivity as first parameter?

Comment: None. Alexander Cavalheiro Becker above made case exactly how you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
xyz(XActivity.class);

void xyz(Class<?> cls)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cls);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

does the job. I tried this now.